# Should I let the app fall in the event of uncaughtException?

Tags: node.js, uncaught-exception

If no catching the event of `uncaughtException`, when uncaught error getting invoked, the whole node.js proccess falls. But, should we let it fall, if yes, by exit immediately or try to gracefull shut it down?

If for example I have an Express app serving thousands of requests in parallel and one of them hitting an API endpoint which cause an uncaughtException. If I don't catch it, the whole process will be exit with exit code of 1 - causing the other requests, which are fine, to drop immediately - can lead to extremely danger situations and unpredictable data pollution.

So instead, why no catch this event, log the error, and keep the process running and set a timeout for the express endpoint by default to not exceed X amount of time?

In such a way, all the others will keep using the API without getting their requests stop in the middle and the one who requested the bad endpoint will get a timeout eventually.

Is it a good practice to catch the process's uncaughtException event and just log the error / email the developer and NOT shutting the server down?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to catch the error, notify the dev team via email (an email just for bugs) and manage the error in a log file. Also and a very important thing is to notify also the final user when an error occurs. If the error has an explanation return it or at least tell the user that the system is having troubleshoots and try it again later.

Comment: But its an uncaughtException, you cannot notify the user since you wasnt ready for this error in first place